# How can I upload a file to Dynamics?

Tags: .net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way (API in Dynamics, supporting API in Azure) in Dynamics to upload a file to it? And by definition, a file is located in the file list for an account, contact, etc. so it would have to be pushed to the appropriate list for a given object.

I'm not asking for a recommendation (not allowed here), just how does Dynamics make this functionality available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short legacy version of the story is:
The entity in which you can store a file in Dynamics is called `annotation` (common name: Note).

The record it will be associated do is held in an entity reference field called "Regarding" (logical name: `regardingid`). The Regarding can be an account, contact, opportunity, etc.... (any entity that allows notes).

The body of the file goes in as a Base64-encoded string.

Following the standard WebAPI CRUD usage for the `annotation` entity should enable you to work with files in Dynamics.

A start on the current version of the story can be found [here](https://jukkaniiranen.com/2019/12/why-would-you-store-images-and-files-in-cds/), thanks to Jukka Niiranen.